# Pothos or not? Identification please

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

I found this plant on the floor it was snapped off its pot.
So I took home and rooted it

Now it has roots I decided to propagate it but I still don’t know what it is!

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Photo of the plant]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Pothos (*Epipremnum*) yes, though at this stage, it's not  impossible it might be the Sweetheart Plant, *Philodendron scandens* [Sweetheart Plant – Philodendron scandens](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217184628/http://www.houseplantsguru.com/sweetheart-plant-philodendron-scandens). It's easy to tell them apart as they grow on a bit - the latter plant has leaves which are broader at the base narrowing down to a distinctive central point, whereas Pothos has narrower leaves at the base. Although there is quite a broad leaf in front at  the bottom of your photo, it does not appear to be quite the proper heartshape, which makes Pothos the more likely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident that it's a Golden Pothos, considering the way it looks in the picture and my observations of both plants, which I'm familiar with. The leaf shape and the style of variegation looks more like a Golden Pothos to me. Also, the surface of the leaves, which is smooth and not so ruffly. It looks less leathery than Philodendron leaves tend to look, too.

Sometimes people lump Golden Pothos in with the Philodendrons (and they say the binomial species name so you know that's what they're doing). I've seen a few pictures that claim to be Heartleaf Philodendrons (which did not mention a breed name, although they tend to claim to be Philodendron hederaceum; Philodendron scandens is an older term for Philodendron hederaceum), but they're probably just Golden Pothos plants. I did a bunch of research and examined a whole bunch of species and cultivars of Philodendron, and I came up with nothing that matches your plant (except for those probable Golden Pothos plants that didn't mention a breed name).

I found Philodendrons that resemble Golden Pothos plants except with a very different leaf shape, however (e.g. Philodendron domesticum 'Variegatum'). Philodendron hederaceum 'Brasil' is a variegated Heartleaf Philodendron, but yours doesn't resemble it.

It should be noted that when these sorts of plants are juvenile and mature, they may have very different leaf shapes and sizes, however. Maybe Philodendron domesticum 'Variegatum' looks like your plant when it's young; I still don't think that's what it is, but it's certainly possible. Even Golden Pothos plants look different when they're 'mature'; most of the houseplants are in the juvenile form.

Here's an example of a picture of a plant that claims to be a Philodendron, which probably is really a Golden Pothos: [Philodendron Scandens (Heartleaf)](https://srobertson3us.blog/2013/08/15/philodendron-scandens-heartleaf-2/).

If what you have really is a Heartleaf Philodendron (which I doubt), then you should hold onto it, and share cuttings with people, because it seems to be a rare one online. Heartleaf Philodendrons grow faster than Golden Pothos plants; so, if you get a Golden Pothos to compare, you should see the difference.

As Bence Kaulics mentioned in a comment to my answer, Philodendrons have a characteristic sheath (it looks kind of papery on Heartleaf Philodendrons). Golden Pothos plants don't have that. Golden Pothos plants seem to have larger leaves, too (at least that was my observation; as both plants mature, their leaf sizes may increase).

Edit: Ahah! I finally found a Philodendron that looks a lot like a Golden Pothos. The pictures verify that it seems to be a Philodendron. The site selling it calls it ["Variegated Heartleaf Philo"](https://www.glasshouseworks.com/philodendron-scandens-variegatum), and I see some other sources around the Internet using the same term; so, I guess we can go with that. However, [this Pinterest page](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/456411743488750916/) has the same image and refers to the variety as Variegatum (I should note that another Philodendron species already has that name, though; but I've seen two species share the name Lemon-lime, or some such, too).

Anyway, when your plant grows out more, it would be great if you would give us an updated picture; then we should be able to determine what it is.

Comment: Unfortunately the stem and nodes at the newest leaves are not visible. The sheaths of the new leaves are a very distinctive mark of *Philodendrons* compared to Pothos which does not really have such sheaths.